# laravel 5.6 carousel bootstrap

Tags: php, laravel, carousel

I am working on my last exam.

So, there might be something obvious that I didn't see.

---

I have created a carousel that works fine.

The problem, is when I call data it doesn't loop trough all my data: [screenshot of the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Hou.jpg)

---

EDIT

Sorry, I think i'm not clear enough :

I managed to have all the data. The db has 4 project named project 1, project 2, project 3 and project 4.

My problem, is that when I loop trough my foreach(), there is only one slide that moves: the first one.

---

My index view:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <title>{{$title}}</title>
            <h1 class="text-center">This is my work:</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-

ride="carousel">
        @foreach($projects as $project)
            <div class="carousel-inner text-center" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <h2>{{$project->name}}</h2>
                    <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="{{asset('Caroussel/laravel.png')}}" height="150" width="150">
                    <p>{{$project->description}}</p>
                    <!--TAGS-->
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                        <h2>{{$project->name}}</h2>
                        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="{{asset('Caroussel/chatbot.png')}}" height="150" width="150">
                        <p>{{$project->description}}</p>
                        <!--TAGS-->
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                        <h2>{{$project->name}}</h2>
                        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="{{asset('Caroussel/iot.png')}}" height="150" width="150">
                        <p>{{$project->description}}</p>
                        <!--TAGS-->
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                        <h2>{{$project->name}}</h2>
                        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="{{asset('Caroussel/php.png')}}" height="150" width="150">
                        <p>{{$project->description}}</p>
                        <!--TAGS-->
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div> 
    @endsection
```

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Project;
use App\Tag;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $title = 'My work';
        $projects = Project ::all();
        return view('projects.index')->with('title',$title)->with('projects',$projects);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My "project" model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','project_tag','projects_id','tags_id');        
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it doesn't get all the projects from the database? Can you a) check what is actually in the database and b) check what `dd(Project::all())` returns?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In my DB, I have project 1, project 2, project 3 and project 4. I managed to get them all. Project 1 should be linked to a laravel img; Project 2 to PHP img etc. Here, in my work, Project 1 is linked to everything: laravel, php, etc. It's also the only one that is "moving".

Comment: Are you wanting 4 different carousels or just one carousel that loops through all projects?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'd like one that loops through all projects.